# Failing spec in Scala/Play during insert into DB(slick)(json request)

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I just try to write a simple spec like this:

```
"saves the record on create" in {
  val request = FakeRequest(POST, "/countries").withJsonBody(Json.parse("""{ "country": {"title":"Germany", "abbreviation":"GER"} }"""))
  val create = route(app, request).get

  status(create) mustBe OK
  contentType(create) mustBe Some("application/json")
  contentAsString(create) must include("country")
}
```

But on execution it throws such an error:

`java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$DatabaseDef$$anon$2@f456097 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@6265d40c[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]`

It works good for `get` request test for `index` page, any ideas how to workaround this ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was `OneAppPerTest` since problems with DB connections: just replacing it to `OneAppPerSuite`solves the problem